# Why is my hp bar not working (should turn green and hp should go up) when i run my code?

Tags: lua, game-development, roblox

I was using a tutorial to make an HP bar and I followed it to a tee (I feel like) but my hp is not working. [Here is the tutorial for reference](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qEI9FY8Okis).

Here is the code

```lua
local greenFrame = script.Parent.Green
local label = script.Parent.TextLabel

local tweenService = game:GetService("TweenService")
local info = TweenInfo.new(.5,Enum.EasingStyle.Sine,Enum.EasingDirection.Out,0,false,0)

local lastHealth = 0

while wait(1) do
    if game.Players.LocalPlayer.Character then
        local currentHealth = math.floor(game.Player.LocalPlayer.Character.Humanoid.Health)
        
        local newFrameSize = UDim2.new(currentHealth/100,0,1,0)
        
        local tween = tweenService:Create(greenFrame,info,{Size=newFrameSize})
        
        tween:Play()
        
        if currentHealth > lastHealth then
            for i = lastHealth, currentHealth, 1 do
                label.Text = tostring(i).."Hp"
                wait(1/(currentHealth-lastHealth))
            end
        else
            for i = lastHealth, currentHealth, -1 do
                label.Text = tostring(i).."Hp"
                wait(1/(currentHealth-lastHealth))
            end
            
        end
        lastHealth = currentHealth
    end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You most likely have something capitalized that shouldn't be, or the other way around.

I recommend temporarily sprinkling lots of `print()` statements around to see what all the values are, to easily tell where it's going wrong.